# Python スクリプトから外部の .py ファイルを実行する方法は？

Tags: python, windows

まず、マクロ用に作られた、関数化のされてない、シンプルな記述のa.pyと言うファイルがあるとします。
a.pyは適当な外部に存在し、変更が許されていません。

```
# a.py  C:\tem\a.py
print("a is")
print("executed!")
```

このa.pyを、b.pyから条件によって呼び出したいと考えています。
流れとしては、

```
# b.py
i = int(input())

if i==1:
    実行(a.py) # 外部にあるa.pyを、ここに記述されているかの如く実行したい
else:
    print("None")
```

のようなことをしたいのですが、可能でしょうか。
お知恵拝借できましたら大変幸いです。

Comment: どれをチェックするか大変迷いましたが、行数及び安定的な汎用性を感じた回答を選ばせていただきました。ご了承いただけましたら幸いです。皆様、詳しいご回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

直に実行しているように見える方法がこちら。
[exec(object[, globals[, locals]])](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.7/library/functions.html#exec)

> この関数は Python コードの動的な実行をサポートします。 object は文字列かコードオブジェクトでなければなりません。文字列なら、その文字列は一連の Python 文として解析され、そして (構文エラーが生じない限り) 実行されます。

[別の Python スクリプトで execfile() メソッドを使用して Python スクリプトを実行する](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/python/python-run-another-python-script/#%E5%88%A5%E3%81%AE-python-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%81%A7-execfile-%E3%83%A1%E3%82%BD%E3%83%83%E3%83%89%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-python-%E3%82%B9%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AA%E3%83%97%E3%83%88%E3%82%92%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)

> execfile() 関数は、インタープリターで目的のファイルを実行します。この関数は Python 2 でのみ機能します。Python 3 では、execfile() 関数が削除されましたが、Python 3 でも exec() メソッドを使用して同じことが実現できます。

> ```
> exec(open("Script1.py").read())
> ```

該当の部分を以下のように記述すれば出来るでしょう。
必要ならばglobal変数やlocal変数の辞書をパラメータに指定することも出来るでしょう。

```
if i==1:
    # 外部にあるa.pyを、ここに記述されているかの如く実行したい
    exec(open(r'C:\tem\a.py','r', newline='', encoding='utf8').read())
else:
    print("None")
```

Answer (score 4):

python 3.6から[`importlib.util.spec_from_file_location`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.spec_from_file_location)を使ってフルパスでモジュールを呼び出せるようになりました。

**サンプルコード**

`module_name`は任意のモジュール名を設定するので、命名規則に反していなければ何でも構いません。
ここでは`filepath`から拡張子なしのファイル名(`a`)をモジュール名としています。

```
from importlib.util import spec_from_file_location, module_from_spec
import pathlib

def 実行(filepath):
    module_name = pathlib.Path(filepath).stem.replace('-', '_')
    spec = spec_from_file_location(module_name, filepath)
    foo = module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(foo)

実行(r"C:\tem\a.py")
```

**参考資料**

- [Python Tips: .py 拡張子の無い Python ファイルを import したい](https://www.lifewithpython.com/2022/09/python-import-module-without-py-extension.html)
- [How do I import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67692)

Answer (score 3):

可能です。
import文の本来の使い方とは異なると思いますが、`import a`でa.pyが呼び出せます。
a.pyとb.pyを同じフォルダに配置する必要があります。

```
#b.py
i = int(input())
if i==1:
    #実行(a.py) # 外部にあるa.pyを、ここに記述されているかの如く実行したい
    import a
else:
    print("None")
```

temp以外でb.pyを実行する場合は、a.pyのパスを追加設定する必要があります。

```
#b.py
i = int(input())

if i==1:
    #実行(a.py) # 外部にあるa.pyを、ここに記述されているかの如く実行したい
    import sys
    sys.path.append('c:\\temp')
    import a
else:
    print("None")
```